# Is this proof correct? Show $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I like proof by contradictions in showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But I can't understand this one>

https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m54x12/public_html/m54densitynote.pdf

[image]

Suppose we fix $b = 2, a = 1$

Then $b - a = 2 - 1 = 1$

Let $N > 1/(b-a)$, where  $N \in \mathbb{N}$, then $N = 2$
Then $A = \{1/2, 2/2, 3/2, 4/2, \ldots\}$

I don't understand the statements after the "Assume Otherwise".

Take $m_1$ the greatest integer such that $m_1/N < a$. Since $a = 1, N = 2$, then $m_1 = 1$

**Then the proof states "$\frac{m_1+1}{n} > b$", but clearly $(m_1 + 1) / 2 = 2/2 = 1 < b$. So this "$\frac{m_1+1}{n} > b$" line is not verified!**

Is there a problem in the proof or is there a problem in my example?

Comment: I'm curious to know what is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't imply directly  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user1952009 I for whatever reason cannot remember a direct proof that show $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I think by contradiction is easier and shorter but only a few are well written

Comment: you should look at the (metric space) completion concept : you have a space with addition and multiplication and a norm which makes sense to $\lim_{x \to 0}$ so you also have the converging sequences concept, and the completion consists of adding the limits of every converging sequences to the space (this is a way  $\mathbb{R}$ can be obtained from $\mathbb{Q}$ and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$  is obvious by construction)

Comment: @user1952009 In some calculus textbooks the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ is simply left out or left as extra material for the interested student. In that type of setting this way of proving it makes sense as it requires no knowledge of how we construct $\mathbb{R}$ (often just taken for granted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the proof is proceeding by contradiction.  That is why it says "Then ${m_1+1\over N}>b$" -- because it's assumed there's no number of the form $m/N$ between $a$ and $b$.  It then proves that this leads to a contradiction, just as you proved that in fact $(m_1+1)/N$ in your situation was actually $<b$ and not $>b$ as assumed.  The contradiction is what establishes the theorem.

This is a case where perhaps a proof by contradiction was not necessary.

Comment: How do they know that $(m_1+1)/N$ will just happens to $> b$. Since you can have a situation where the interval $(a,b)$ is quite far apart

Comment: They don't know, and in fact it isn't true.  What they're doing is, they've assumed the contrary of what they want to show, i.e., they've assumed that no element of $A$ is in $(a,b)$.  They want to prove that this assumption leads to a contradiction.  They then start deducing stuff -- the first thing they deduce is that $(m_1+1)/N>b$ -- and then they chug until a contradiction appears.  It's a very common proof technique.

Comment: aha I see the logic now